# How to fix 'a hash tag move' error in html?

Tags: html, css

I make the web site nav used the position fixed style. And main content height size is calc(100vh - nav_size). I click the tag move context in the main content so, main content up the 65 pixels. I don't understand why overflowed 65 pixels. I Think "col-6" height extend parent height(main content).

I tried insert options(position: static, remove relative or thing). but not solved this problem.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="nav" style="position:fixed; height:65px">
        some code...
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper" style="padding-top:65px;">
        <div class="wrapper-2" style="postion:absolute; top:65px">
            <div class="wrapper col-12" style="height:calc(100vh - 65px)">
                <div class="col-6" style="height:100%">
                    some code...
                </div>
                <div class="col-6" style="height:100%">
                    Contexts...
                    <a herf="#context-1"/>
                    ...
                    Context-1
                </div>
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code was example. This result is if you click the a tag so, your focus moving the context-1. And then  overflow 65 pixel  of the "nav".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="wrapper col-12" style="height:calc(100vh - 65px)"> 
// if you use bootstrap "col-12" change "row" classes try again
```

please write back

Comment: my example site is similar to yours. Check it out. https://vlog.netlify.com

Comment: I tried remove padding! But, not fix this bug. I edited my style top option into my html code in this post . Maybe I think click the a tag so, not action top style.